# Get image height from constrained width value image?

Tags: php, image, height

I was wondering if it is possible to do some kind of function which will get the height of a constrained width image? I can get the original height by using:

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($path."/images/".$image->image);
```

But my images on the page are constrained to be 580px wide:

```
<img src="/images/<?php echo $image->image; ?>" width="580" height="????" border="0" />
```

I was wondering if it were at all possible to get the new height of the constrained width image?

Comment: Surely this is just basic arithmetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all about ratios. You already have the ratio of the width/height for the original. Now you just need to get it in terms of your 580px width. width/height is to 580/X

```
function getHeight($width,$height){ //originals 
    return (580*$height)/$width;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked :) Will accept the answer when the timer allows me to!

Comment: whenever you can that'd be great!